# FabricJs Ctrl C + Ctrl V

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a copy paste action using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> with fabricjs.

I managed to do something. The object that I'm selecting and doing copy paste is copied but if I press again <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> the item is places inside the last one. And if I select items are changing position.

Copy paste actions:

```
if (map[17] && map[67]) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        for(var i in canvas.getActiveGroup().objects){
            var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveGroup().objects[i]);
            object.set("top", object.top+5);
            object.set("left", object.left+5);
            copiedObjects[i] = object;
        }                    
        console.log(copiedObjects);
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
        object.set("top", object.top+5);
        object.set("left", object.left+5);
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
        console.log(copiedObjects);
    }
}else if(map[17] && map[86]){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(copiedObjects);
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
            canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
        }                    
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
        canvas.add(copiedObject);
    }
    canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
}
```

I made a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5a1wkfb/)

Please go into JsFiddle and select that object. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> twice and then select the two object. You'll understand what is my problem then.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution To this problem I have create new object from the copied object
and add it to `canvas`

instead of doing

```
canvas.add(copiedObject);
```

I am doing this

```
var object = fabric.util.object.clone(copiedObject);
object.set("top", object.top+5);
object.set("left", object.left+5);
copiedObject1 = object;
canvas.add(copiedObject1);
```

and here is my jsfiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/n5a1wkfb/2/